# Selecting QListWidgetItem with qtbot.mouseClick

Tags: python, pytest, pyside2, qlistwidget, pytest-qt

How can I click on a QListWidgetItem with qtbot.mouseClick?

I tried it with the following code, but it fails on the final assert:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def widget(qtbot):
    widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    qtbot.addWidget(widget)
    for i in range(10):
        widget.addItem("Item %s" % (i + 1))
    widget.show()
    qtbot.wait_for_window_shown(widget)
    return widget


def test_aa_click_item(qtbot, widget):
    row = 7
    item = widget.item(row)

    rect = widget.visualItemRect(item)
    center = rect.center()

    assert widget.itemAt(center).text() == item.text()
    assert widget.currentRow() == 0

    qtbot.mouseClick(widget, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, pos=center)

    assert widget.currentRow() != 0
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#visualItemRect) points out:

> ### QRect QListWidget::visualItemRect(const QListWidgetItem *item) const
>
> Returns **the rectangle on the viewport** occupied by the item at item.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The position center is with respect to the [viewport()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) so you must use that widget to click:

```
def test_aa_click_item(qtbot, widget):
    row = 7
    item = widget.item(row)

    rect = widget.visualItemRect(item)
    center = rect.center()

    assert widget.itemAt(center).text() == item.text()
    assert widget.currentRow() == 0

    qtbot.mouseClick(widget.viewport(), QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, pos=center)

    assert widget.currentRow() != 0
```